# How to use jetpack navigation component / navigation graph for bottom navigation tab?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have an activity contains a bottom navigation graph which has 5 tabs, I want to connect each tab to fragment using navigation graph, how can I linked it in navigation graph and manage the back stack.

Note: I don't want to use fragment transactions and manual code, I only want to use the navigation graph which is provided by jetpack navigator.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#bottom_navigation

Comment: Thanks a lot @CommonsWare

I hope it will help me, surely I will let you know

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare , it helps a lots

and also following google sample I found is give me a solution.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components